# APC Caching with variable includes

Tags: php, apc, opcode

I have been doing some research on APC Caching with PHP and found that conditional includes just don't work.  Like:

```
if($a) {
    include('a.php');
} else {
    include('b.php');
}
```

My question is:  Can I get around this with variable includes?  Such as:

```
if($a) {
    $file = 'a.php';
} else {
    $file = 'b.php';
}
include($file);
```

Would the latter code be APC-cached successfully?

Answer (score 2):

APC will still cache the file, just at a later stage in parsing your app. It's recommended to always include both instead if this is possible.

If you are tied to the conditional includes, you should consider that maybe this is not a big deal at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The APC package includes a file, apc.php (it ends up somewhere under /usr/share/doc/, I think, so take a copy), that will show you what files are being cached (you need to edit it and set a password to see full path) - do you know for definite it's not working, or are you going off the chinese-whispers that seem to surround APC?

Answer (score 0):

Saw this post now.
Thought it might be useful for someone.

While using APC, if `apc.stat=0` is used, then *relative paths* won't work in `include, require` etc.
**You need to use absolute paths.**

Eg:
Consider a script inside a folder named myfolder.

Relative paths will cause errors:

```
<?php include 'script2.php'; ?>
```

Instead use absolute path:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myfolder/script2.php'; ?>
```

Refer the following links for more:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59493
http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2112260&p=12919262#p12919262